# type of textarea in doctrine symfony1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony1

i am wondering how to add types of textarea in symfony1 schema file,because i have tried all posibble ways but all become a textbox fields in forms

for exmaple

```
 file_desc: clob(65532)
```

Or

```
   file_desc: text
```

and result is

```
'dddd'  => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
```

i want it should be like

```
 'dddd'               => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(),
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

With symfony 1.4/doctrine, you only need to use the type `clob`

`file_desc: { type: clob }`

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/defining-models.html#clob

Answer (score 0):

You should just define your column as `string` without specifying the length.

Like this:

```
file_desc: { type: string }
```